# Search MySQL database with Filter options selected by the user. Database structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I have a form which the user can fill out, and I wish to search the MySQL database for entries  that the user has selected. For instance, If the user enters a keyword, and checks option 2 and 3, I want to search the database for the keyword AND options 2 AND 3.

I'm not sure how to set up the database however. Will I need an extra column in the table for each option, or is there a way to store an array within a table? Another technique that occurred to me was to have a separate table for the options.

I've seen this done before, but I'm not sure on the proper execution. If someone knows the proper way to do this, that would be great.

EDIT: This is a database of places, (say, music stores), and the options are different instruments sold. Now when a user fills out the form, I want to return a list of stores whose names include the 'keyword' string AND which sell the instruments selected by the user.

I'm not sure how to set up the database in order to do a proper query. Should I have each option as a separate column with a boolean value, or can I have a column with an array of boolean values?

Note: 'Instruments' is just one of many options. I also want to be able to filter by other criteria

The HTML :

```
    <form>
         <input type="text" name ="Keyword" value="keyword"/><br/>
         Option 1<input type="checkbox" name="Option 1" value="option1"/><br/>
         Option 2<input type="checkbox" name="Option 2" value="option2"/><br/>
         Option 3<input type="checkbox" name="Option 3" value="option3"/><br/>
         Option 4<input type="checkbox" name="Option 4" value="option4"/><br/>
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Proposed DB structure:

```
id  |  store_name  |  guitar  |  piano  |  saxophone  |  cello  |
 1     mike\'s music   true      false      false        true
```

OR:

```
id  |  store_name  |  instruments  |
1     mike\'s music    Array[2]
```

Comment: You are missing the `name` attribute, which is pretty much mandatory

Comment: I think you need to give us more information about the data.  It isn't clear what sort of data you are likely to have in your database, tables and columns etc, so it is difficult to comment further.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean, but you could concatenate the options that are selected with a certain delimiter and store that.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed DB structure:

```
stores
id  |  store_name
 1     mike\'s music

instruments
id  |  desc
 1     guitar
 2     piano
 3     saxophone 
 4     cello

stocks
id  |  store_id  |  instrument_id
1      1            1                 
2      1            4
```

So the query can be something like this :

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT store_name
          FROM  stores 
          INNER JOIN stocks ON stores.id = store_id
          WHERE 1 = 1 ";
if ($keywords!="") {
          $query .= "AND store_name like concat('%','".$keywords."','%') ";
}
if ($option1!="") {
    $option[] = 1;
}
if ($option2!="") {
    $option[] = 2;
}
if ($option3!="") {
    $option[] = 3;
}
if ($option4!="") {
    $option[] = 4;
}
if (count($option)>0) {
    $query .= "AND instrument_id in (".implode(",", $option).")";
}
```